# Find bottom-lef index of numpy array that satisfies all elements in this array within a given size equal a certain value

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a 3D numpy array (image) resulting from opencv contours drawing on white background. Basically the image values are either 0 (for black lines) or 255 (for white background).

I want to put some text in this patch, and I know the bounding box text size.

Now I need to find a part in the image which is equal or bigger in size than the bounding box text size where that part in the image is all white (value is 255 in the three RGB channels). Once this part is found, I want its bottom-left index so I can use it to put the text.

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, there is a fine line between a badly formatted question (deserving a down vote) and a head scratcher which adds to the community capabilities. I hope that given the answer below, I get to have some upvotes for the question and the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I Managed to solve it. below is the code heavily commented to be understood.
The core answer to the question is:

```
white_patches = np.argwhere(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(patch,(txt_h,txt_w)).all(axis=(-2,-1)))
```

The above line gets top-left index of each window in the image of size `(txt_h,txt_w)` where all elements in the window are non-zero.

**Full Code**

```
def CBN(img, colors):
    canvas = np.ones((img.shape[0],img.shape[1],img.shape[2]),dtype='uint8') * 255 #used to draw the final CBN image

    #used to draw a negative (black) of the contour to exclude areas not suitable to place text of next contour.
    negative = np.ones((img.shape[0],img.shape[1]),dtype='uint8') * 255

    #release contours from its hierarchy and have it as an unnested list of contours
    contours = []
    for ind, color in enumerate(colors):
        color = np.asarray(color, dtype='uint8')
        mask = cv2.inRange(img, color, color)
        cnts,hier = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        c = [{'cnt':cnt,'ind':ind+1} for cnt in cnts if
            cv2.boundingRect(cnt)[2]>10
            and cv2.boundingRect(cnt)[3]>10
            and cv2.contourArea(cnt,False)>100]
        contours.extend(c)
    contours = sorted(contours, key= lambda x:cv2.contourArea(x['cnt'],False), reverse=False) #arcLength can also be used
    txts = tuple([str(x['ind']) for x in contours]) #texts to be added
    contours = tuple([x['cnt'] for x in contours]) #contours to be drawn

    for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
        cv2.drawContours(canvas,[cnt],-1,0,thickness=1)

        #identify suitable place to put text
        cnt_x, cnt_y, cnt_w, cnt_h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        patch = negative[cnt_y:cnt_y+cnt_h, cnt_x:cnt_x+cnt_w, :] #get a patch from the negative

        font_scale=1
        flag = True
        while flag:
            if font_scale >0.5: #try to find a suitable place to put the text with font scale from 1 to 0.5
                txt_w, txt_h = cv2.getTextSize(txts[i], cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, font_scale, 1)[0] #get the text size in w x h
                if patch.shape[0]>txt_h and patch.shape[1]>txt_w: #check patch is bigger than text

                    #select indices that when considered as a top-left coordinate for text result in complete white box that is inside the contour
                    white_patches = np.argwhere(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(patch,(txt_h,txt_w)).all(axis=(-2,-1)))
                    white_patches = white_patches.tolist()
                    white_patches = [x for x in white_patches if
                                    cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt, (x[1]+cnt_x,x[0]+cnt_y), False)>0 #TL of text in contour
                                    and cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt, (x[1]+cnt_x+txt_w,x[0]+cnt_y), False)>0 #TR of text in contour
                                    and cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt, (x[1]+cnt_x+txt_w,x[0]+cnt_y+txt_h), False)>0 #BR of text in contour
                                    and cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt, (x[1]+cnt_x,x[0]+cnt_y+txt_h), False)>0 ] #BL of text in contour

                    if len(white_patches)>0: # if there are top-left coordinates found, use the first coordinate (any one can be as good) to place text
                        txt_x = white_patches[0][1]+cnt_x
                        txt_y = white_patches[0][0]+cnt_y+txt_h
                        cv2.putText(canvas, txts[i], (txt_x, txt_y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, font_scale, 0, 1)
                        flag = False
                    else: #no top-left coordinates found, decrease font scale and try again
                        font_scale -=0.1
                else: #patch is smaller than text, decrease font and try again
                    font_scale -=0.1
            else: #we reached minimum possible font size. Place text at centroid of contour
                M = cv2.moments(cnt) #use contour centroid
                txt_x = int(M["m10"] / M['m00'])
                txt_y = int(M["m01"] / M['m00'])
                cv2.putText(canvas, txts[i], (txt_x, txt_y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, 0, 1)
                flag= False
     return canvas
```